# Return Data on MAX Value (Without Affecting Result of MAX)

Tags: sql, max, ms-access-2010

I want to return whether or not we offer service in a particular location. The heirarchy is Zip Code > State > CountryWide

So if you enter a TX zip-code, it will first see if there's a zip entry. If not, it will check for a TX entry. If still no hits, it will check countrywide policies.

To achieve this, I have a Calc field that indicates the level of specificty. Zip Codes are level 3, States = 2, CW =1. So a simple MAX will let me know what level of data I'm dealing with. An example of my query for this is:

```
SELECT Service_Availability.Service_Product, MAX(Service_Availability.Specificity) AS Spec
FROM Service_Availability
WHERE Service_Availability.State = "TX" OR Service_Availability.State = "CW"
GROUP BY Service_Product;
```

**Now here is where my issue comes in.**

I want to know if service is available at the highest level of specificity provided. However, I don't have the correct approach...

```
SELECT Service_Availability.Service_Product, MAX(Service_Availability.Specificity) AS Spec
FROM Service_Availability
WHERE (Service_Availability.State = "TX" OR Service_Availability.State = "CW") 
AND Service_Availability.Available = TRUE
GROUP BY Service_Product;
```

This returns the highest level of specificity where Service is available, not if the service is available at the highest level of specificity.

To say another way, suppose the zip is 68123 (Omaha, Nebraska).

My db shows that we do provide service in Nebraska, but for whatever reason, we specifically cannot provide service in Omaha (68123). I want the db to see I have zip level data, and use that to determine availability (FALSE).

I understand why my code is the wrong approach, but I'm not sure which direction to come at it from. Help is appreciated!

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do. Please post your table structure some sample data and then the desired result.

Comment: There is another pattern that you could use instead of MAX/GROUP BY ... it's combining SELECT TOP 1 with an ORDER BY. Many times it makes your logic simpler. I would suggest exploring this.

Comment: @Dave: The OP doesn't appear to be looking for a single record result, so TOP 1 won't work here.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?  You are talking about zip codes, your sample query is selecting `Service_Product`, and it is grouping by `Carrier_Product`.  I'm confused.

Comment: @marc_s i'm using Access 2010. I had tried to add Access as a tag, but it said I was too new to invent tags, sorry.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff The GROUP BY was a typo, my apology. It should also be Service_Product

Comment: @AaronContreras . . . I still don't understand what output you want.  Do you want to know what level a zip code will be serviced at for a given product and zip code?  Do you want to know all zip codes that cannot be serviced?  Do you want to know what products can be serviced in a zip code?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sorry for being unclear, let me better explain. It's not feasible for us to define in each zip code whether or not our service is available. Too many services for too many products. So we start by saying "We don't have Service A nationwide" (specificity 1). "But we can offer it in these states" (2). "However, we cannot offer it in these zip-codes (even if we can offer it in that state)" (3). So I want to enter a zip code and figure out if there's a zip-level entry for it. If there is, use whatever rule was entered. If not, see if there's a state rule. If not, nationwide rule?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Let's look at two cities in Nebraska, Omaha and Lincoln. The DB says we have Service A in Nebraska, except in 68123 (Omaha). When 68123 is entered, it will find zip info for it, and say "Service not offered". However, when 68502 (Lincoln) is entered, it won't find a zip-level entry for it. So it will then examine the state, and say "Service is offered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to INNER JOIN your initial query (almost) as a subquery to get this to work:

```
SELECT Service_Availability.Service_Product, Service_Availability.Specificity 
FROM Service_Availability 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Service_Availability.Service_Product, MAX(Service_Availability.Specificity) AS Spec
    FROM Service_Availability
    WHERE (Service_Availability.State = "TX" OR Service_Availability.State = "CW")
    GROUP BY Service_Availability.Service_Product ) max_spec
  ON Service_Availability.Service_Product = max_spec.Service_Product
  AND Service_Availability.Specificity = max_spec.Spec
WHERE Service_Availability.Available = TRUE
```

Comment: Your explanation on how this would function is exactly what I'm looking for, so we're on the same page. However, your query (the first one) is showing the highest level of specificity at which the service is available. 

  For example, Service A is available in the state, but not in the zip, so it shouldn't show in the list. However, what I'm seeing is that it shows with a Specificity of 2 (state level).

Comment: Does 'Service A' have a table entry for zip (Specificity=3) with `State` set to 'TX' or 'CW' and `Available` set to `FALSE`?  It probably wouldn't because for a zip specificity, the `State` field would probably hold a zipcode - is that right?  If so, then you need to expand your WHERE clause to search on all possible State values for this state - and that would include all zipcodes.  You can do a joined search if these codes (state and zip) exist in a table somewhere...

Comment: Close. The Availability table has STATE, ZIP_CODE, AVAILABLE, and SPECIFICITY fields. State will always have the state in it, and the zip will either have a zip or "DEFAULT". So Service A has an entry for for NE 68123 FALSE 3 (state, zip, available, spec). There's also an entry for Service A NE DEFAULT TRUE 2.

Comment: :) Definitely on the right track, but 2 issues are present. I don't think you'll be able to troubleshoot these issues though, so I'm going to accept your solution. 1, it returns a few extra results, which are duplicates. For example, Service C will show up twice on the list, with the same specificity. Weird, but not necessarily an issue. There's no discernable pattern that seperates those with dupes from those without. 2, one service is not on the list at all, even though it's available at spec-level 2. There's another service exactly the same that does appear though, so I have no idea why...

Comment: ... Service C and Service D both have a zip entry (FALSE) and a state entry (TRUE). Service C comes back, but D does not. Seems almost arbitrary.

Comment: You can use `SELECT DISTINCT` in the outer query to remove duplicates. I have no idea, why some results aren't appearing - perhaps showing what records are available can shed some light on this.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT worked to remove the dupes, thanks. Looking over the results again, I see that Service C (see previous comment) is showing a spec-3. However, it is un-available at spec-3 (available at spec-2). I think your code is showing the max spec, but showing results that have availability at whatever spec-level it can find :\

Comment: Check the results from the inner subquery - do they correctly show the max spec-level (available or not) for each service_product as you expect it to?

Comment: No, the incorrect spec-level shows up in the inner query, as well. I started adding fields to the select for more clarity into what's going on; the zip code for Service C is from another state entirely. I'm looking over the sql, but I don't see why this would be the case. It pretty specifically demands "TX" or "CW". I added .state into the outer SELECT, and I'm definitely looking at other states.

Comment: This appears to be data related - I'm not sure if I can help more with this...  Perhaps try removing the GROUP BY and MAX and check if the basic inner query itself works as expected.

Comment: I got it! I added the TX/CW clause to the outter WHERE. I'm guessing that the inner query would determine spec-3 was the max for Service C in TX/CW, but then the outter query would look through the FULL table to find a Service C, spec-3 entry that was True (regardless of state). The reason Service D didn't show is because there's no spec-3 entry in any state for it :) Thank you for all the help!